# single nginx config for multi apps

Tags: python, nginx, amazon-ec2, uwsgi

I am hosting my web app on linux EC2 instance. This web app contains 2 small python application called `app1` & `app2`.

What i want:

request `/sales` -> show web on `app1`.

request `/operation` -> show web on `app2`.

My nginx config.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80;
    server_name  _;
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
    }

    location /sales {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/sales.sock;
    }

    location /operation {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/operation.sock;
    }

}
```

When i try access from the browser, the first `/sales` show result as expected, but the other `/operation` return `Error 404` instead of `app2` website.

What i'm doing wrong?

Please help, thank you.